# Should I use QVariant or MyCustomType* to pass an object from Qml to C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have C++ class User

```
class User : public QObject
{
    Q_PROPERTY(QString login READ login WRITE setLogin NOTIFY loginChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString password READ password WRITE setPassword NOTIFY passwordChanged)
    ...
}
```

Also I have Qml SignIn form with button which calls this code when clicked:

```
var user = userComponent.createObject()
user.login = loginTextField.text
user.password = passwordTextField.text
signInInteractor.signIn(user)
```

SignInInteractor is a C++ class

```
class SignInInteractor : public QObject
{
    Q_INVOKABLE void signIn(User* user);
    Q_INVOKABLE void signIn(QVariant user);
    ...
}
```

And my question is should I use `User*` or `QVariant` as argument type? What advantages and disadvantages they have?

Comment: Use `QObject`-derived types for interacting with QML when possible. Not only better type-checking, they expose properties and invokable methods while packing the type to `QVariant` implies your C++ function supposed to first recognize the type and cast the variant value to it. I would use the variant if I need to pass different types of parameter to the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your custom type is `QObject` derived, so you can easily work on it on a `QObject *` level from QML. You will be able to access properties, slots or invokables, and functions directly, without having to do anything extra.

You will however have to add the `Q_OBJECT` macro, which is currently missing from your code, so the types get the MOC treatment that will generate the necessary meta data for them, which is what QtQuick will be using for introspection.

If you pass it as a variant, it will be like an opaque pointer, you won't able to do much with it from QML other than to pass it around. It only makes sense when the type is unsupported by QML, and `QObject` is more like a first class citizen there.

Comment: Also there is `Q_GADGET` for types, when `*Changed` signals for properties are not needed.

Comment: @Orient - it is not just that. Gadgets are always passed around by value, copied and whatnot. Which means you can't get them by reference, which means you cannot preserve object identities. And to make the deal even "sweeter" you even **cannot** work with gadgets on pointer level explicitly. Gadgets + pointers + QML is a no-go. That is a rather severe design limitation.